Status error 500 when deploying Vue web app with Vite and Nginx (within docker compose)
I'm currently improving my web development skills and working on a project using the following tech stack:

Frontend: Vue
Build tool: Vite
Deployment: Nginx (locally)

I've deployed the app locally, but when I try to access http://localhost:8080, I encounter a 500 Internal Server Error. I’ve checked the browser's dev tools, but the sources tab doesn’t provide any additional information, making it difficult to identify the issue.
I’ve included the project repo here for reference.
I’m not sure where the problem lies — whether it’s with my Nginx configuration, Vite build process, or something else in the Vue app. I’d really appreciate any guidance or hints on how to debug this error.
Thanks in advance for your help!

This is the folder structure:
├── Makefile
├── app
│   ├── capacitor
│   │   └── capacitor.config.ts
│   ├── dist
│   ├── # NOTE: This directory is built from the `web-builder` docker compose service
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   └── chunk-vendors.a51efc20.css
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── js
│   │       ├── app.38461d29.js
│   │       ├── app.38461d29.js.map
│   │       ├── chunk-vendors.6a82c935.js
│   │       └── chunk-vendors.6a82c935.js.map
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── public
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── App.vue
│   │   ├── main.js
│   │   ├── router
│   │   │   └── index.js
│   │   └── views
│   │       └── Home.vue
│   └── vite.config.js
├── docker-compose.yml
├── dockerfiles
│   ├── android-build.Dockerfile
│   ├── web-build.Dockerfile
│   ├── web-serve.Dockerfile
├── scripts
│   └── generate-env.sh
└── server
    └── nginx.conf

This is the dockerfile responsible for building the dist (web-build.Dockerfile):
FROM node:20-alpine AS build
COPY app /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install && npm install @vue/cli-service
CMD npx vue-cli-service build

This is the dockerfile responsible for deploying the dist (web-serve.Dockerfile):
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY /server/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

And this is the relevant part of the docker compose file that puts them together:
services:
  web-builder:
    build:
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/web-build.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app/dist:/app/dist

  web-server:
    build:
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/web-serve.Dockerfile
    ports:
       - "8080:80"

This is the vite.config.js file:
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    // base: './',
    root: '.',
    build: {
        outDir: 'dist',
        emptyOutDir: true,
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                main: 'public/index.html'
            }
        },
        manifest: true
    },
    publicPath: '/'
});

This is the index.html file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Urban Umbrella</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="module" src="../src/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

This is the main.js file:
import {createApp} from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router';
import routes from './router';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue-next/dist/bootstrap-vue-next.css';

import {createBootstrap} from 'bootstrap-vue-next';

const router = createRouter({
    // history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(createBootstrap());
app.use(router);

app.mount('#app');

This is the App.vue file:
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
});
</script>

This is the router.js file:
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router';
import Home from '../views/Home.vue';

const routes = [
    {path: '/', component: Home},
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});

export default router;

Finally, this is config.nginx:
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
events
{
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http
{
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    server
    {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        location /
        {
            root /app;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html
        {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}


Vite is officially recommended, while Vue CLI is still usable but unmaintained. This is the project that was generated from Vite template that was slightly modified and switched to Vue CLI for some reason. It makes sense to keep using Vite, unless there are reasons to not do this.
The modifications that are needed to make it regular Vite template that is expected to work normally:

move ./public/index.html to ./index.html (this is not an actual static file but a template for HTML file generated at build)

change ../src/main.js to ./src/main.js in index.html

remove rollupOptions section in vite.config.js, Vite uses the said index.html location by default

remove npm install @vue/cli-service in Dockerfile, since Vue CLI isn't used

replace CMD npx vue-cli-service build with CMD npm run build, so it runs build script that the project was configured with


Make sure that generated dist conforms your expectations, it's supposed to be viewable apart from Docker container when served with any server that is configured for client-side routing, e.g. npx serve --single dist.
The project has a problem, it creates a router twice, in main.js it should be import router from './router' instead of import routes from './router', and const router ... variable should be removed.

This worked. Thanks @Estus Flask for taking the time to go through all these files.

Glad it helped. It's rather trivial once you remember what a workable thing is supposed to look like

DISCLAIMER:
The following changes allowed me to successfully build and run the project, reaching the homepage. However, as @Estus Flask mentioned, this approach is more of a workaround than a production-ready solution.
For a more reliable, production-grade fix, please refer to his answer.

OLD ANSWER:
The following changes worked for me:

Remove this line from index.html:
<script type="module" src="../src/main.js"></script>


Add the following vue.config.js file:
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

export default {
  configureWebpack: {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './public/index.html',
        inject: true,
        chunks: ['app'],
      }),
    ],
  },
};



The issue seemed to arise because the main.js file was located in a parallel directory (an "uncle" folder) to where the build process expected it. By explicitly specifying its inclusion, I was able to resolve the problem.

Self-answers are good, but your solution looks like a quick fix. It's not just fixing few lines. You had Vite/Rollup and changed it to Vue CLI/Webpack without an apparent reason. The latter is not maintained and not recommended to use. "I suspect this was because it was located in a directory parallel to the expected folder " - this can certainly cause problems in any setup indeed

@EstusFlask As my expertise is more centered around data engineering and languages like Python, Java, and C#, I don't have deep insight into the intricacies of JavaScript tooling like Vite/Rollup vs. Vue CLI/Webpack. I can tell you though, coming from better structured and well-documented languages, that JavaScript feels chaotic and lacking in consistent documentation, especially due to the fast-moving ecosystem. Please feel free to propose any better solution, as it would be gladly appreciated since my goal here is learning

I'd suggest to focus on fixing Vite setup instead of using obsolete build tool. Basically your setup has both, and the project was created from Vite template (this is where <script type="module" src="../src/main.js"> line comes from). To make it clear, @vue/cli-service command is Vue CLI. Currently Vue officially recommends to use Vite in the docs

@EstusFlask even before posting the question on Stack Overflow I already tried on my own for a long time, without success. Do you know if there is any effective way to "force" the presence of a specific file into the final build with the regular vite cli? e.g. inside the vite.config.js file?

Depends on a file and its role. You put static files to public/ that are supposed to be moved to dist/ as is , and you put resources that are supposed to be bundled to src/assets/ and explicitly import them

Could you please give a quick look at the main.js file and tell? I personally don't think think it should be conceptually put into src/assets

Can you clarify what file you talk about? main.js itself?

Correct, main.js

There's no such problem in general with Vite. This is bundle's entry point, a bundle cannot exist without including it so there's no need to forcibly do this except for the <script type="module"> part that I mentioned. Did you check my answer?
